# Using Apache Flume to write logs from MapReduce job into HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, log4j, hdfs, flume

I am trying to write logs from MapReduce job into HDFS. I am using Apache Flume NG.

**My environment:**

- Java 6
- Log4j 1.2.16
- Apache Hadoop 2.3.0
- Apache Flume 1.4.0

**Problem #1**

I have created simple MapReduce job as Maven project and I have used `logger.info()` in my classes. When my job is completed I can see my logs in syslog file.

I would like to create my own log4j configuration and write logs to console too.
How can I do this? Where do I have to put log4j.properties file? Should I modify general Hadoop conf/log4j.properties?

**Problem #2**

I would like to write logs to HDFS. But I don't want to use `tail -f` command and write the content of syslog file. I would like to write logs only from my classes - messages from `logger.info()` method.

Is this possible using Apache Flume NG?
Or maybe can I do this easier?

I had an idea to implement Flume Log4j Appender in log4j.properties (for example on localhost, 44444 port). In Flume NG configuration I wanted to use the same address for Avro source and through memory channel write logs to HDFS.

Is this good solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem #1

Which console? Remember the tasks are running on different JVMs. So there is no single console. If you want the logs from the Driver then that would be simple configuration.

> Problem #2

What you are attempting is a generally a good solution. Flume appender is available in log4j project : [Log4J 2 Flume Appender](https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite-examples/tree/master/logging)

[1](https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite-examples/tree/master/logging): http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FlumeAppender or the other option : [Kite SDK](https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite-examples/tree/master/logging)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding problem #2 - where should I put log4j.properties with my Flume Appender? In my Maven project or in hadoop/etc/log4j.properties file?